# PHP Regular Expression validation to allow only upto 1-5 dots in a Email-ID/string

Tags: php, regex, regression

In PHP, how to add a regression to validate a string if it has more than 5 dots (.) in a Email-ID/string

For example: asdf.bn.jk.ui.tyqwer.sdfg.qw12@gmail.com

If it has more than 5 or 7 dots, I need to show the validation message.
Kindly help please.

Comment: "more than 5 or 7"? What about 6?

Comment: Best way for email is `filter_var` function. example: `$mail = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with regex on this, just split the string on your delimiter, count the items and subtract `1`.

```php
$s = 'asdf.bn.jk.ui.tyqwer.sdfg.qw12@gmail.com';
$dotCount = count(explode('.', $s)) - 1
```

Comment: Its working, -1 helped me to avoid the last one

Answer (score 1):

Try `substr_count();` function like :

```php
$email = 'asdf.bn.jk.ui.tyqwer.sdfg.qw12@gmail.com';
echo substr_count($email, '.');
```

Comment: I swear, I've been writing PHP professionally for a very long time and I keep learning about these one-off functions that have been in core forever and are optimized for a single thing! I totally agree, use this over my `explode` version.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about this because it's completely acceptable to have a legitimate email address with many dots. Some domains even have several dots:

```
sir.richard.g.smith.iii.1234@mortgages.loancompany.co.uk
```

When you start filtering out emails based on assumptions of their legitimacy, you are going to eventually block someone that is legitimate and just happens to have a really long / dotty email address.

As Hamham said, just use filter_var() with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL:

```
$mail = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

It should validate whether an e-mail address is correct or not (it will work for all e-mail addresses as long as they have a FQDN domain), and then you can let the spam filters take care of determining if something is legitimate or not. That's the job of the spam filter, not the job of the e-mail address parser.